# Magento 2 REST API Custom Order Status Endpoint?

Tags: magento, magento2

I am using the Magento 2 REST API:

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/rest/list.html

Is there an endpoint to pull custom order statuses? For example, a user can have these statuses:

Complete
Processing
Pending

A user adds a custom status called on hold. Can I pull a list of statuses from the site?